# How to write object to disk(save in a file)

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am using example code below from accord.net framework website, Any ways this code is working fine what i want to achieve is save object to the file..
I want to save DynamicTimeWarping class type object, kernel in following code to the disk(Save in a file)

```
   DynamicTimeWarping kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(length: 3);
```

I have tried using XMLSerializer but visual studio is giving error that it can not be serialized because it does not have parameterless constructor.

```
   double[][][] sequences =
    {
  {
    new double[] { 1, 1, 1 }, // first observation of the first sequence
    new double[] { 1, 2, 1 }, // second observation of the first sequence
    new double[] { 1, 4, 2 }, // third observation of the first sequence
    new double[] { 2, 2, 2 }, // fourth observation of the first sequence
},

    new double[][] // second sequence (note that this sequence has a different length)
    {
    new double[] { 1, 1, 1 }, // first observation of the second sequence
    new double[] { 1, 5, 6 }, // second observation of the second sequence
    new double[] { 2, 7, 1 }, // third observation of the second sequence
},

new double[][] // third sequence 
{
    new double[] { 8, 2, 1 }, // first observation of the third sequence
},

new double[][] // fourth sequence 
{
    new double[] { 8, 2, 5 }, // first observation of the fourth sequence
    new double[] { 1, 5, 4 }, // second observation of the fourth sequence
}
};



int[] outputs =
{
-1,-1,  // First two sequences are of class -1 (those start with {1,1,1})
    1, 1,  // Last two sequences are of class +1  (don't start with {1,1,1})
};


double[][] inputs = new double[sequences.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < sequences.Length; i++)
  inputs[i] = Matrix.Concatenate(sequences[i]);


// Now we have to setup the Dynamic Time Warping kernel. We will have to
// inform the length of the fixed-length observations contained in each
// arbitrary-length sequence:
// 
DynamicTimeWarping kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(length: 3);

// Now we can create the machine. When using variable-length
// kernels, we will need to pass zero as the input length:
var svm = new KernelSupportVectorMachine(kernel, inputs: 0);


/  / Create the Sequential Minimal Optimization learning algorithm
var smo = new SequentialMinimalOptimization(svm, inputs, outputs)
{
Complexity = 1.5
};

// And start learning it!
   double error = smo.Run(); // error will be 0.0


// At this point, we should have obtained an useful machine. Let's
// see if it can understand a few examples it hasn't seem before:

double[][] a = 
   { 
     new double[] { 1, 1, 1 },
      new double[] { 7, 2, 5 },
      new double[] { 2, 5, 1 },
      };

double[][] b =
   {
    new double[] { 7, 5, 2 },
  new double[] { 4, 2, 5 },
  new double[] { 1, 1, 1 },
 };



int resultA = System.Math.Sign(svm.Compute(Matrix.Concatenate(a))); // -1
int resultB = System.Math.Sign(svm.Compute(Matrix.Concatenate(b))); // +1
```

Comment: Have you tried adding attribute to your class which you want to serialize? [Serializable()]

Comment: ...so add a parameterless ctor

Comment: @carl that class is built-in class of accord.net framework. i can not add any attribute myself

Comment: Then make a derived class which would inherit from it. Or is it sealed?

Comment: @ carl it's sealed i guess.

Comment: What do you mean "i guess". Try it out.
[Serializable()]
public class SerializableClass : <accord.net framework class name>{}

Comment: You could try adding a parameterless ctor using a partial class.

Comment: @user3544843 Then other "hackish" way would be to recreate this class via reflection and  serialize that new class. Yet not sure how would that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this Class in that framework has `SerializableAttribute` added.

This example should do:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i am getting error (it can not be serialized because it does not have parameterless constructor.)

Comment: Well looks like they had no testing on that when developing this class. There has to be parameterless constructor... I can see that base `Accord.Statistics.Kernels.KernelBase` has one, maybe this is going to be enough for You to serialize ? Plus it doesn't look like it's sealed `public class DynamicTimeWarping : KernelBase, 
 IKernel, ICloneable, IDisposable`

Comment: It,s working but with this i am only able to save public member, i need to save non-public members too.